# Update existing DDB with new attribute

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, boto3

My DDB table contains "uploadedTimeStamp" and now I want to add another attribute called "trimmed_timestamp" to all existing items in the pre-existing table.
There are almost 7k records but the below boto3 script updated only 2k items.
Is there anything I am missing out? How do I ensure all my items are updated?

Or should I go with **batch_execute_statement** method to insert attribute? Which method will be better if I need to update my production DDB with 0 downtime?

```
import boto3
from datetime import datetime

# Initialize DynamoDB client

dynamodb = boto3.resource('dynamodb')
table_name = 'test-table'
table = dynamodb.Table(table_name)

# Scan the table and update items

response = table.scan()
for item in response['Items']:
    # Get the timestamp attribute
    timestamp = item['uploadedTimeStamp']
    # Trim the timestamp
    trimmed_timestamp = timestamp[:10] # extract dd-mm-yyyy

    # Update the item with the new attribute
    update_expression = 'SET trimmed_timestamp = :value'
    expression_attribute_values = {':value': trimmed_timestamp}
    table.update_item(
        Key={'consumerId': item['consumerId']},
        UpdateExpression=update_expression,
        ExpressionAttributeValues=expression_attribute_values
    )
```

Comment: I think this is because: your scan or query more likely than not is not returning all results because the results being returned exceed the 1MB maximum per call.

Answer (score 1):

If you fetch more than 1MB of data from DynamoDB you have to implement [paginateion](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Scan.html#Scan.Pagination).

> DynamoDB paginates the results from Scan operations. With pagination, the Scan results are divided into "pages" of data that are 1 MB in size (or less). An application can process the first page of results, then the second page, and so on.

[Here](https://github.com/aws-samples/aws-dynamodb-examples/blob/master/DynamoDB-SDK-Examples/python/WorkingWithScans/scan_paginate.py) is an example of how to implement it in boto3.